go get is telling me my package does not exist, but it does
I'm trying to use go get so that I can eventually build a simple example program that uses a package from a module that I wrote and put out on github. But it tells me this.....
$ go get github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings@v0.0.0
go: module github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test@v0.0.0 found, but does not contain package github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings

The repository is public and the package does exist. I have only three files in the repository, one is just the README.
This is my go.mod file:
module github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test

go 1.23.0

The other file is called greetings.go which I got from one of the examples. It starts with the following line:
package greetings

In the program I am trying to import the greetings package into, I have the following:
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings"
)

The module has one tag which is v0.0.0.
Here is the weird thing. If I try to get just the module without the package name, it appears to work.
$ go get github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test@latest
go: added github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test v0.0.0

However, if I try to build after that, I get this:
$ go build
hello.go:8:5: no required module provides package github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings; to add it:
    go get github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings

I followed the directions from Publishing a module in the go documentation.
It said to run the go list command in order to make the module available and that seemed to work.
$ GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go list -m github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test@v0.0.0
github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test v0.0.0

But still, when I try to run go get, it says there is no such package.
I tried both of the following:
go clean -cache
go clean -modcache

No luck. I still get the same error.
What do I need to do to get this to work?

You cannot import "github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test/greetings" as it is not sub-package but "root" package of your module. More idiomatic would be to name your module "github.com/nonfungible-human/greetings" in this case.
If you want to keep it this way your greetings package is accessed directly from mod-test (which you have to give different import name as it contains -).
Example:
package main

import foo "github.com/nonfungible-human/mod-test"

func main() {
    foo.Hello("baz")
}

